# Can I increase the ceiling height in my mobile home?

Tags: ceiling

In the main living area of my 1990s single-wide mobile home (living room, kitchen, dining area), the ceiling is 8' with a decline from the center that brings it down to 7', which is the height of the ceiling in every other room. Even if only in my bedroom, and even if only partially, I'd love to expand the height of the ceiling. Please forgive my obvious ignorance here...although I'm relatively new in the DIY space, I'm serious about it and am a quick learner.

To be clear, I'm not asking about modifying my home structurally to increase the area inside. Instead, I'm wondering about the possibility of "reclaiming" some of the space, primarily in my bedroom, between the existing ceiling and roof by simply moving the ceiling up, even if only by 6". There are no *obvious* existing structural barriers for this, but what is to consider in assessing the practicality of such a thing?

Also, I'm not in a park, and I own both the home and the land.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Just to be explicitly clear, your question is "Can I raise the ceiling in my mobile home?" or "How can I raise the ceiling in my mobile home?" - You haven't actually asked a question, so I'm assuming that's what you're after. Please take a minute to [edit] your post to make that explicitly clear, then take the [tour] and browse through the [help] while waiting for an answer (or two) so you can learn how to make the most of this site.

Comment: I have never raised a roof but have repaired a couple. My question would be are you on your own property or in a park? Modifying the structure may be an issue for moving it later. I know the last one I repaired the park owners were a pain in the butt I was helping a friend, they wanted to see my license and mentioned something about changes. I was just putting a new membrane on for her. I was none two polite and all the old lady’s came out giggling.

Comment: Welcome. Yes, what is the question exactly? If you're asking whether it can be done, sure. If you're asking whether _you_ can do it, we have no idea. Please revise to clarify what you're trying to learn, and avoid any peripheral chatter not pertaining to the actual question. [We're not a discussion forum](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: The first thing is to figure out *why* the ceiling goes down to 7'. Since 8' is a more "normal" height (and drywall, plywood, 2x4s, etc. are typically in 8' lengths to match), there is probably a good reason. Take a look outside - maybe there is mechanical equipment (e.g., HVAC) on top of that part makes use of the "extra' foot of space?

Comment: If the exterior roof is consistent across the length of the trailer, but the ceiling inside is lowered in places, it may be that some of the mechanical bits that @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact mentioned are between the ceiling and roof and you wouldn't be able to take advantage of that space without redoing half the mechanicals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much depends on your situation (park lot rental .vs. own land, **very** different) but I will guarantee that building an add-on room with more height (and more space, yay!) would be far less trouble and expense than trying to "raise the roof" on a mobile home. The structure is already "just barely adequate" and modifying it is a huge undertaking for minimal benefit.

If you own the land you are on, it can be quite practical to build enough real house (a piece you can afford at a time) that you can eventually sell the mobile part and have it towed away. If you don't own the land that's not remotely practical.

Otherwise, flip the bedroom and the living room functions. Or pull up a flatbed trailer and build a "tiny house" on that with the headroom you want for your bedroom, and either or both parts can be towed away to a new site as needed.

Comment: You just changed the way I see the whole issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No. Your roof is built to minimal height standards for cost, insulation, travel height, wind handling, etc. You basically have ceiling joists, a relatively small space for insulation, and the roof. There's no extra height available there. You will need to raise the upper roof surface to make room for livable space below.

Here's a short list of things that need to happen to raise the roof in part or all of your home:

- Roof demolition
- Wall framing
- Roof framing
- Plumbing vent extension (if present)
- Utility vent/flue extension (if present)
- Roofing repair (shingles or membrane, edge flashing, penetration flashing)
- Electrical wiring extension/reconfiguration
- Wall and roof insulation & vapor barrier
- Exterior siding & soffit
- Drywall hanging and taping
- Wall and ceiling texture and painting
- Building permits
- Inspections

Whether this project is appropriate for you is entirely a matter of prerogative, budget and legality and not ours to say.

One other consideration is that mobile homes tend to be subject to wind damage (tipover). Raising the height of yours exacerbates that problem.

Comment: I have not seen a mobile home with shingles, or soffits most have flat roofs, but would agree with the rest of the list. Modulars do have all of those Much more like a stick built than a mobile. If it can be done +

Comment: Maybe it's regional. Around here many mobile homes have traditional asphalt roofs, though soffits tend to only be on the rakes. [Image search showing that](https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile+home&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ALeKk02kNAoyIJUCyTEGlBNGqbjafOSgaA:1594304917762&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3sKXSsMDqAhWJVc0KHcrrBpAQ_AUoAXoECBMQAw&biw=1618&bih=947).

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can raise the roof.   Given unlimited budget you can raise the roof, install marble floors, and have a fireplace on each end.

Is raising the roof on a mobile home a good idea?   F@@k no.

Honestly it is a good thought.   I grew up part of my life in a mobile home and grandmother owned a mobile park.   I get the ceiling issue.   But most of these (all almost)have specific weldings for the roof load.   But these "beams" also give lateral support to the walls - these are enclosed units.

Example - On older homes not taken care of they may develop rust.   If the rust hits the support beams/crosses we would have to weld a new piece of metal - usually outside.   The detachment due to rust would cause the home to become "wavy" and move when walking.   Eventually the movement causes other supports to wear and welds/screws/bolts to loosen and home is done.   (newer mobile homes have the same issues but hide these joints better which make them look better but also harder to repair)

Isherwood has a list of things.   What it is not explaining well is the lateral load the roof is holding.   This means to add height you will have to attach that to something - which means creating all new walls along the perimeter or some really expensive metal beams (plus welding).   So to summarize you are basically building a house inside your mobile home - so why not just build a house?

Answer (score 0):

I lived in a mobile home for 4 years in the 1970s. Based on this I think you should not attempt to raise the roof in a 7 ft section. The original structural integrity would be called into question. You would probably reduce the resale value.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done, but would basically require building that whole bedroom over with 8' (or taller) studs and putting up a new roof over it. That would be the best for retaining structural integrity and would also make the mobile.home safe to move in the future Any other method of extending the ceiling is asking for trouble.... like a roof collapse.